# Prevent app from being killed in background by iOS Camera app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios-background-mode

I have an GPS-Tracking-Fitness-App where the user can track workouts in the background. All of that is working fine. No problem.

But SOME users - not many, but some - have the problem, that opening the camera app on their phones will kill my app.
I can't reproduce it on my phone, but I once had such a phone in handy for debugging, and in the Xcode memory-debugger I could see that opening the camera-app there took about 2-3 GB!!! of ram and my app instantly got a low-memory-warning and was then killed.

I guess my app can't really do something about that?!? It does not use that much RAM itself. So I am wondering if I can somehow prevent that. I guess I did not miss any "background-mode : super-important-to-the-user" or so setting? :)
Or is there a way to at least trigger a Push-Notification in such case? Not sure...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try enabling significant location change mode as well as normal location updates in order to get re-launched, but this will require the user to move some distance.  Are you using HealthKit workout tracking?

Comment: On the watch we are using HealthKit, yes. On the phone we are exporting our workouts to HealthKit once we are done.
The significant updates would help relaunch yes! Good point. But the user will still loose quite a bit of his/her workout until then... But yes... better that nothing.